# how would I change the outline color of an svg path with d3?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I have an SVG image that looks like this:

[image]

I was playing around with the styling in Chrome Dev Tools, trying to change the outline color. However, I'm having problems doing this. The CDT Styles tab has the following info:

```
element.style {
   fill: cyan;
   stroke: red;
   stroke-width: 10;
}
```

As you can see in the picture, the `fill` style attribute works as expected. The `stroke` and `stroke-width` are not working in the way that I'm intending.  `stroke` and `stroke-width` seems to be applied to an area around the outline but I'm trying to change the characteristics of the outline itself.

Any idea how I would do this? In [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/extkHkDOyhCvDbY9ZLso?p=catalogue), the SVG path element definition is in the file `MySvgElement.txt`.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] in the question. The plunkr is neither complete nor in the question itself.

Comment: Well, looking at the image, I can see the outline is red and has a width of 10 px around a cyan inner. What other would you expect from that style definition? To me this works as expected. In addition to Robert Longson's comment, please also include a clear statement of what you expect it to look like.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that the map probably has two paths that form that area:

1. The "fill" part, which you are changing the fill and stroke of.
2. The "border" path (or paths), which are black and are somewhere else in the SVG file.

Comment: Right now, I am confused... Is this an answer? I took this for granted! This can easily be seen by putting the `<path>` provided in the plunk in an `<svg>` element: https://jsfiddle.net/cb730qpv/

Comment: The path that is in that fille looks like the path I've called #1 in my answer.  You need to find path "#2" and change the stroke value of *that* one.

Comment: Oh, I am not the author of the question ;-) I commented on that one, though, as I feel—in addition to R. Longson's comment—there is some information missing to answer this. My analysis was the same as yours, but I am still not sure what OP is after.

Comment: Ah. Right. I agree OP needs to provide a working [MCVE]. My answer was an educated guess that I hoped would shortcut the process.